# Client machine unable to connect to the local ftp repository server. Writes an error: Failed to synchronize cache for repo '***', ignoring this repo

Tags: ftp, yum, vsftpd, repository, rhel8

Please help me to understand where I was wrong, because I've read a lot of articles also I've seen lot's of Youtube videos, but all the time in the end I've got the same error result.

So, on my  **Server machine (192.168.25.146)** I've install from the rpms: `ftp`, `vsftpd`, `createrepo` and `dnf-utils` packages. Then, I've moved inside OS iso directory **(/run/media/dmitriy/RHEL-8-0-0-BaseOS-x86_64/)** and copied all it's content to the **/var/ftp/pub** directory.

Next, I've moved to the `vsftpd` config file and  changed next:

**anonymous_enable=YES**

**anon_upload_enable=YES**

**chown_uploads=YES**

**chown_username=daemon**

After that,I've addede port 21/tcp and service to the `firewalld`:

```
public (active)
target: default
icmp-block-inversion: no
interfaces: ens160
sources: 
services: cockpit dhcpv6-client ftp ssh
ports: 21/tcp 22/tcp
protocols: 
masquerade: no
forward-ports: 
source-ports: 
icmp-blocks: 
rich rules:
```

Then, I've configured my local repo file (**/etc/yum.repos.d/server.repo**):

```
[server]
name=server
baseurl=ftp://192.168.25.146/pub
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

Then, I've enabled booleans:

```
getsebool -a | grep ftp
ftpd_full_access --> on
```

After that I,ve performed **createrepo /var/ftp/pub**

Finally, I've restarted `vsftpd` and the command yum repolist displayed me that everything on server machine nice:

```
[root@control ~]# yum repolist 
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Last metadata expiration check: 0:27:12 ago on Sat 04 Jul 2020 12:15:21 AM EEST.
repo id                                             repo name                                                                 status
server                                              server                                                                 6,328
ansible-2.8-for-rhel-8-x86_64-rpms                  Red Hat Ansible Engine 2.8 for RHEL 8 x86_64 (RPMs)                           13
rhel-8-for-x86_64-appstream-rpms                    Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - AppStream (RPMs)                  10,766
rhel-8-for-x86_64-baseos-rpms                       Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - BaseOS ( RPMs)                      4,834
```

Also, see the `ftp` connection to the localhost:

```
[root@control ~]# ftp localhost
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost (::1).
220 (vsFTPd 3.0.3)
Name (localhost:root): anonymous
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
230 Login successful.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp> ls
229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||17555|)
150 Here comes the directory listing.
drwxr-xr-x    3 0        0          380928 Jul 03 19:33 pub
226 Directory send OK.
ftp>
```

Now, I went to my **Client machine**
I configured my repo file in ** /etc/yum.repos.d/client.repo

```
[root@ansible1 ~]# cat /etc/yum.repos.d/client.repo 
[client]
name = client
baseurl = ftp://192.168.24.146/pub
gpgcheck = 0
enabled = 1
```

I've enabled booleans, made the same changes in **/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf**, installed ftp, vsftpd, but when I logged to the ftp I do not see my packages.

I also don't do all these things on client machine, but just configured repo file, but result the same, when I perform **yum repolist** I've got:

```
[root@ansible1 ansible]# yum repolist
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
client                                   0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:21    
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'client', ignoring this repo.
```

FTP connection from client to server:

```
[root@ansible1 ~]# ftp 192.168.25.146
Connected to 192.168.25.146 (192.168.25.146).
220 (vsFTPd 3.0.3)
Name (192.168.25.146:root): anonymous
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
230 Login successful.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp> ls
227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,25,146,121,86).
ftp: connect: No route to host
ftp
```

I've also added

```
#/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
 pasv_max_port=40000
 pasv_min_port=
```

Firewall

```
[root@control ~]# firewall-cmd --list-all
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: ens160
  sources: 
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client ftp ssh
  ports: 21/tcp 22/tcp
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
   rich rules:
```

Please help me to understand where I was wrong!!!

Comment: You should try to FTP from the actual client machine to the actual server, not from localhost.

Comment: When I type `ftp` and double TAB I see just localhosts proposed addresses, when i typed server' ip, I obtained an error: 500 OOPS: vsftpd: cannot locate user specified in 'chown_username':deamon
Even after i commented field **chown_username=deamon**

Comment: Do you have a user by that name?

Comment: Why did you specify that username if it does not exist?

Comment: Added main text, olease see it, I've logged in but have such a message: **ftp: connect: No route to host** howor where to write this route ?

Comment: Anybody have some ideas?

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your post where you explain why you have added `chown_username=daemon`. I already asked about this but you did not respond. Can you point me to this reason?

Comment: I've deleted this row and now I am able to connect, but see the message **No route** when I'm trying to enter **ls** or other commands. Why? If its so important - mistakenly, because as I mentioned previously I'm new and try to do as mentioned in articles or videos that I've read/seen.Are you able to help me to understand how or where to write this route?